# Why can't I assign a value to a const int field?

Tags: c#, int, constants, variable-assignment, build-error

okay, so I have an int lets say called "Var1":

```
public const int Var1 = 0;
```

now I want to assign this to an Int32 value like so:

```
Var1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

It will then give me this error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Help? I'm new to this, sorry if this is a simple mistake.

Comment: If you want to assign something to it don't make it a `const`.

Comment: A constant is supposed to be constant. You cannot reassign it.

Comment: I remember a guy asking why the statements after `return;` weren't executed.

Comment: Is posting a question on SO really simpler than googling "c# const"?

Comment: @Rotem Well, I actually had no idea why the error was occurring. So I couldn't have known it was the const that was tripping up my program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`const`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword means that the field is a *constant* and thus can only be assigned *once*: at declaration time.

You have assigned the value `0`, therefore you can't overwrite it with a new value later.

Remove the modifier to fix your problem.

Comment: thanks! I ended up fixing it by replacing const with static.

Comment: @WillBrickner good, but make sure you understand the [difference between instance members and static members](http://csharpcomputing.com/Tutorials/Lesson3.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Think about what you are doing there:

```
public const int Var1 = 0;
```

`const` means **CONSTANT**. It means you **cannot** change it.

Answer (score 1):

A `const` is a *constant*; you cannot change its value at runtime (and the iNitial alum must be a constant expression evaluated at the compiler).

Just remove the `const` and things should work:

```
public int Var1 = 0;
// ...
Var1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `Var1` as [const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) (which is quite an oxymoron in itself).

`const` members cannot be modified, so they cannot be assigned to. If you want `Var1` to be mutable, remove the `const` modifier:

```
public int Var1 = 0;
```

Note that you do not need to explicitly initialize the member to `0`, since it is the default value of the `int` type. You only have to write:

```
public int Var1;
```

I would also suggest making the member `private` and exposing it to the outside world through a a `public` property, which is considered as a better encapsulation practice:

```
private int _var1;

public int Var1
{
    get {
        return _var1;
    }
    set {
        _var1 = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Var1 is declared as a const field, that means you cannot change its value. If you want to change the value of Var1, then you must remove the "const" qualifier.